# How to solve a nonliear dynamic optimization with recursive constraints using python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, optimization, dynamic, nonlinear-optimization

I am a new learner of python and I am trying to use Scipy.optimize.minimize to solve a nonlinear optimization problem. But I don't know how to write the recursive constraint.

The constraint is like:

```
ta(i) = tb(i-1) + c(i)/d(i) ;  i=1,2,3,...,n
```

where `c(i)` is a constant.

When I use `def` and set the variable as a list like `ta[i]`, it makes an error. So could anyone please tell me how to write the recursive constraint? Thanks.

Here is the code I tried:

```
V = np.zeros(11)
TA = np.zeros(11)
TD = np.zeros(11)
obj = np.zeros(10)
c = list(np.arange(10))

def objective(V):
    for m in c:
        v = V[m]
        ta = TA[m]
        td = TD[m+1]
        ##D[],P[],E[] are lists from data, they are parameters
        d = D[m+1]
        p = P[m+1]
        e = E[m+1]
        obj[m] = d/24*v**2+(td-ta)+p*max((ta-e),0)

    vn = V[10]
    tn = TA[10]
    en = E[10]
    pn = P[10]
    return sum(obj)+Pifo*d/24*(k1*vn**2+k2)+p*max((tn-en),0)
def constraint1(TA):
    for m in a:    
        v = V[m]
        ta = TA[m]
        td = TD[m]
        d = D[m+1]
        return ta-td-d/v
def constraint2(TD):
    for m in c:
        ta = TA[m]
        td = TD[m+1]
        ##S[],WS[] are lists from data, they are parameters
        s = S[m+1]
        ws = WS[m+1]
    return td-max(ta, ws)-s
def constraint3(V):
    return V-Vmin
def constraint4(V):
    return Vmax-V

con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1} 
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}         
con3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3} 
con4 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint4} 
cons = ([con1,con2,con3,con4])

solution = minimize(objective,V,constraints=cons)
```

Here is the model in math format.

[model math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4y3h.jpg)

Comment: You should post some Python code - not Matlab or pseudo-code - showing what you have attempted so far. You don’t show any code nor tracebacks, and I doubt anyone’s mind-reading skills are so powerful to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Infinity77 Thank you for your advice! I have edited the question and post my code and the model. Sincerely hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Looks better, but still I can’t run it as it stands. Can you post what traceback you are getting?